# Is Snowflake equivalent of SQL WITH(NOLOCK)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is Snowflake the equivalent of SQL WITH(NOLOCK)?

I was working on update operations on SnowFlake tables but in some cases, I faced deadlock.
are there any recommendations to deal with these situations?

Comment: It's in their documentation [Snowflake Transactions](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/transactions.html). You can compare that to [Sql Server transaction isolation levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) like READUNCOMMITTED  which is the equivalent of NOLOCK.

Answer (score 4):

SQL WITH NOLOCK is actually more like a dirty read, which means you could get partially updated data when you run a SELECT against a table that is being updated.  Snowflake never provides a dirty read.  You will always get the pre-update dataset returned to you until the update is committed.  So, in that regard, I believe they are different.